# will "cp -rf ' (SSH) maintain files that are not in the source folder ?

Tags: ssh, terminal

When using the SSH command `cp -rf` will it delete files that are not in the source structure or will it just ignore them ?

eg: if your are coping all files from foo/vault to bar/vault if bar/vault has additional files will these files be left untouched or wil they be removed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in the target directory will not be deleted.  They will remain untouched, while the files from your source directory will be copied in.

So for your example above, files in bar/vault (which are not present in foo/vault) will not be deleted when the copy is executed.